# Implementing an Onion Proxy in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, routes, protocols, tor

I am looking to implement an onion proxy that uses the TOR onion routing protocol from scratch in python 3.
My ultimate goal is to have a working OP (onion proxy) on my Raspberry Pi 3 that I can connect to with my computer to browse the internet with TOR. 
Note that I want to do this FROM SCRATCH as opposed to just downloading the TOR browser.

So far, I have been reading the official TOR design documentation to understand exactly what my onion proxy will need to do. However, I feel like I need more documentations\examples to really understand what I'm doing.

So, if anybody could refer me to further documentation or even better a working example, it would much be appreciated!
Also, if you have any tips for me on how to get started with this project, I would be more than glad to hear it!

Reference (this is currently what I'm reading):
https://svn-archive.torproject.org/svn/projects/design-paper/tor-design.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: You'll improve the quality of the answers to your question if you show us what you've tried and what isn't working with it. Please read about creating a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I agree with you at @MatthewBarlowe however, I haven't tried anything yet, right now I'm focused on how to get started and look at working examples.